# pragma optimize("", off) doesn't disable optimizations fully

Tags: c++, windows, debugging, visual-c++

I am looking at the documentation here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/chh3fb0k.aspx

I also searched existing SO questions. The existing questions discuss how to turn off optimizations for one file, but not what to do in case all optimizations are not off.

Currently, when debugging in `release`, I need `#pragma optimize("", off)` outside of functions in a particular source file to disable optimizations. Using `debug` configuration for the whole project is not an option.

However, this is not *completely* disabling optimizations for that file i.e. I still get out of order instructions and cannot put breakpoints in certain locations. Is this expected or am I really not turning off *all* optimizations for the source file? In the latter case, how *do* I turn off all optimizations for a file. In the former case, what are my options?

Comment: Why, exactly, do you need to turn optimizations off? You can still debug optimized code. Out of order instructions and setting breakpoints should not be a problem with symbols.

Comment: It is with our codebase. Even with `#pragma optimize("", off)` I am unable to get any meaningful information from some of the symbols/variables. Some breakpoints that I set _jump_ a few lines of code when I start debugging (which is normal behavior in VS where it jumps the lines of code that cannot have a breakpoint set due to optimization and sets the breakpoint to the next available line of code)

Comment: [**/Od**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aafb762y.aspx) - this full disable all optimization

Comment: If you're doing a retail build, you normally get /GL (Whole program optimization), /O2 (Optimize for speed) and /Oi (intrinsics) depending on the platform. The local /O2 and /Oi optimizations can be overridden using the optimize pragma, but you'll still get the default /GL optimization in retail that can enregister locals and reorder code. Rather than work at function level, you can compile just the one file of interest using /Od, while leaving the rest retail, and do a separate link pass. I believe that will keep /GL from optimizing that one file.

Comment: @ColinRobertson I'll give that a shot and put that as an answer if it works.

Comment: Out of curiosity, whoever voted to close the question, why?

Comment: @Samaursa, did you test it? is it working?

Comment: (I realize this is old)
@Ale sorry, we weren't able to - due to the complexities of the build system, it was not possible to have different settings just for one file.